# Flagging many comments that are no longer needed?

Tags: discussion

While clarifying a question, a trail of comments is typically left behind. Many of these comments are not needed after the post is edited. These comments are deleted sometimes by moderators since they are no longer needed. However, if not, one can flag them as "no longer needed" for the reasons mentioned [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280/should-obsolete-comments-be-removed).

Is raising too many flags of these types bad or are they encouraged? I want to check with moderators if it is fine with them since handling too many of such comments could be frustrating especially when there are other important pending flags.

Comment: In my personal opinion, there are far better things to flag about.

Answer (score 5):

I can only speak for myself --

I think raising those flags is wonderful.  I'm happy to handle those flags; I don't find it frustrating.   I appreciate that members of the community are helping with moderating the site.  Flag away.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I think this is fine, go ahead.

In general, I wouldn't worry about raising too many flags. As long as the flag is valid, it is useful information for the moderator team. If there are other more important flags pending, we can simply choose to handle those first.